# What is causes a ModuleVersionNotFoundException in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I've used Gradle before, but have never configured it myself. I'm running openjdk 11.0.4 and have installed Gradle using the official install guide, including adding it to the windows path. All I've been doing is adding the line:
'''

```
implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:2.2.0'
```

to my build.gradle file. I'm editing using Intellij. Here is my full build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.61'
}

group 'lastname'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:2.2.0'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

When I try to sync the project I get the following from my Gradle tab
[gradle_tab_view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RhPO.png)

The build output I get is this:

```
4:20:29 PM: Executing tasks ':classes :testClasses'...

> Task :compileKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:2.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/kittinunf/fuel/fuel/2.2.0/fuel-2.2.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/kittinunf/fuel/fuel/2.2.0/fuel-2.2.0.jar
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
4:20:30 PM: Tasks execution finished ':classes :testClasses'.
```

Any advice on what could be broken or maybe what clearly isn't implemented would be appreciated, this has greatly hindered my work flow, and I feel like it has to be something small or stupid that I'm overlooking. I feel like I'm at war with Gradle to get Fuel to work in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error output means that Gradle could not find the Fuel dependency in the two locations is searched. Both locations are in `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/`, which is Maven Central. Gradle looks in this repository as you have told it to through `repositories { mavenCentral() }`.

However, Fuel is not published to Maven Central. If you use a search site like [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.kittinunf.fuel/fuel/2.2.0), you will see where it was found. In this case it says:

> Note: this artifact it located at Spring Lib Release repository
>   (https://repo.spring.io/libs-release/)

But his is misleading, because that is just a mirror as some Spring library apparently depends on it. If you head over to the [Github](https://github.com/kittinunf/fuel) page for Fuel, you will see that it is in reality deployed to [Jitpack](https://jitpack.io/#kittinunf/fuel). So the correct solution is to add Jitpack to the list of repositories in Gradle:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        name "jitpack"
        url "https://www.jitpack.io"
    }
}
```

This is not all that clear from the Github page as is is only explained in the section for snapshot releases. But it is not all that uncommon to have to do a bit of detective work to track down which repository to use for a given dependency when it is not present in any of the common ones.

By the way, `testCompile` is deprecated and you should use `testImplementation`. And since this is a Kotlin project, you will probably want to switch from the Groovy DSL to Kotlin DSL at some point.